# Calling filter from other filter in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Is anyone can tell me is it possible to call filter from other filter in AngularJS.
If it not possible do any one know if it possible to call service from filter ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call one filter from another filter in angular.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20715726/how-to-call-one-filter-from-another-filter-in-angular-js)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

> In HTML Template Binding:

```
{{ filter_expression | filter : expression : comparator}}
```

> In JavaScript:

```
$filter('filter')(array, expression, comparator)
```

So you can use the second notation to call your second filter from the first, in JavaScript, by injecting `$filter`.

```
app.filter('filterA', function($filter) {
    return function(text) {

        return $filter('filterB')(text);
    }
});
```

[Usage shown in the docs here.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter)

Edit:

As noted, you can also inject filters directly to another filter as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20715726/how-to-call-one-filter-from-another-filter-in-angular-js).

```
app.filter('filterA', function(filterB) {
    return function(text) {

        return filterB(text);
    }
});
```

[Usage shown in the docs here.](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter)

Comment: And, yes, you can inject another service into a filter.