# Choose angularjs filter dynamically based on condition in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I am looping through list of items using ng-repeat. There are some values which i want to display as simple numbers like "435" or "43", some i want to display as double like with 2 decimal places "545,32.43" or "343.32", some values are percentage which i want to display like "75%", and some are currency which i want to display as "$65,434".

I know angularjs provides filters for all kinds of operations (number, currency, percentage) etc.

But how can i chose one of the filter dynamically based on condition?

### javascript

```
config:[
    {key:"Issue County",value:50,valColor:'#4caeed', type:'integer',dec_places:0},
    {key:"Issue Average", value:10.5356 ,valColor:'#4caeed', type:'double', dec_places:2},
    {key:"Issues Percentage", value:57, valColor:'#e54343', type:'percentage', dec_places:2},
    {key:"Total Amount", value:65000, valColor:'#4ca977', type:'currency', dec_places:0}
]
```

### html

```
<ui class="subCardDiv" ng-repeat="conf in item.config">
    <li  style="display: inline;">
        <span class="cardDivKey" style="padding-top: 2px;">{{conf.key}} </span>
        <span class="cardDivVal" ng-style="{color:conf.valColor}" style="padding-top: 2px;">{{conf.value | number:conf.dec_places}} </span>
        <span ng-if="conf.text" class="cardDivText" style="padding-top: 2px;">{{conf.text}} </span>
    </li>
</ui>
```

Comment: Build your own filter and pass the `conf` object to it. Inject the `$filter` service and call the appropriate filter when you need to (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20715931/215552) for how to do that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ipcMfB03cXcKj2JUTNwj?p=preview)

**ng-switch-approach**

```
  <ui class="subCardDiv">
    <li style="display: inline;" ng-repeat="conf in item.config">
      <span class="cardDivKey" style="padding-top: 2px;">{{conf.key}} </span>
      <span ng-switch="conf.type">
          <span ng-switch-when="double" class="cardDivVal" ng-style="{color:conf.valColor}" style="padding-top: 2px;">{{conf.value | number:2}}</span>
      <span ng-switch-when="percentage" class="cardDivVal" ng-style="{color:conf.valColor}" style="padding-top: 2px;">{{conf.value+'%'}}</span>
      <span ng-switch-when="currency" class="cardDivVal" ng-style="{color:conf.valColor}" style="padding-top: 2px;">{{conf.value | currency}}</span>
      <span ng-switch-when="integer" class="cardDivVal" ng-style="{color:conf.valColor}" style="padding-top: 2px;">{{conf.value | number:0}}</span>
      <span ng-switch-default class="cardDivVal" ng-style="{color:conf.valColor}" style="padding-top: 2px;">{{conf.value}}</span>
      </span>
      <span ng-if="conf.text" class="cardDivText" style="padding-top: 2px;">{{conf.text}} </span>
    </li>
  </ui>
```

**controller function option**

```
  $scope.displayConf = function(conf) {
    if (conf.type == 'double') {
      return $filter('number')(conf.value, 2);
    } else
    if (conf.type == 'integer') {
      return $filter('number')(conf.value);
    } else
    if (conf.type == 'percent') {
      return conf.value + '%';
    } else
    if (conf.type == 'currency') {
      return $filter('currency')(conf.value);
    } else
      return conf.value;
  };
```

And you can also write a generic filter

**generic-filter approach**

```
filter('myFilter', function($filter) {
  return function(conf) {
    if (conf.type == 'double') {
      return $filter('number')(conf.value, 2);
    } else
    if (conf.type == 'integer') {
      return $filter('number')(conf.value);
    } else
    if (conf.type == 'percentage') {
      return conf.value + '%';
    } else
    if (conf.type == 'currency') {
      return $filter('currency')(conf.value);
    } else
      return conf.value;

  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this with Angular would be to define your own custom filter. Inside that filter you can run JavaScript code to conditionally apply other filters to your value.

There's plenty of documentation on using and creating filters in AngularJS and how powerful they can be.

Then to call a filter inside your own filter, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20716233/2999446) is pretty good

Note that all this is for AngularJS v1, not AngularJS v2